# I am getting error in android studio

Tags: android, sdk

I am getting error like Failure [Instal_Failed_Order_SDK].As I am learner I am really finding difficult to get output. Please provide me a proper explanation regarding this error. I am using this  to do my project on sensortag.

Answer (score 0):

Your app has a min SDK version higher than your device.

To fix it you should know what version of android is installed on your device then find relative sdk version and change it in your build.prop or in manifest

```
<uses-sdk **android:minSdkVersion="15"** android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    **minSdkVersion 17**
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
```

}

I think that it's build.prop in your case